# Resetting interval on click

Tags: jquery, function, setinterval, clearinterval

I have seen similar questions but I don't think any of the ones I seen will do. Mine involves resetting interval on several functions together. It's a fading slideshow with small navigation buttons. I can get the buttons to work  but I want the slideshow to stay on that slide for the interval time (4.5 seconds) and then carry on from there instead of skipping to where it is. Hope that makes sense. Any help much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#slider div:gt(0), #slideinfo p:gt(0)").fadeOut()

        $("#circleholder div.circle1").click(circle1)   
        $("#circleholder div.circle2").click(circle2)
        $("#circleholder div.circle3").click(circle3)
        $("#circleholder div.circle4").click(circle4)
        $("#circleholder div.circle5").click(circle5)



            setInterval(function timer(){
                circle1();
            },22500);
        setTimeout(function () {
                circle2();  
            setInterval(function timer(){
                circle2();
            },22500);                   
        }, 4500);

        setTimeout(function () {
                circle3();
            setInterval(function timer(){
                circle3();
            },22500);                   
        }, 9000);

        setTimeout(function () {
                circle4();
            setInterval(function timer(){
                circle4();
            },22500);   
        }, 13500);

        setTimeout(function () {
                circle5();
            setInterval(function timer(){
                circle5();
            },22500);
        }, 18000);


        function circle1 () {       
            $("#slider div.slide, #slideinfo p").fadeOut(1000)
            $("#slider div:eq(0), #slideinfo p:eq(0)").fadeIn(1000)
            $("*").removeClass("activecircle")
            $("#circleholder div.circle1").addClass("activecircle")
        };

        function circle2 () {       
            $("#slider div.slide, #slideinfo p").fadeOut(1000)
            $("#slider div:eq(1), #slideinfo p:eq(1)").fadeIn(1000)
            $("*").removeClass("activecircle")
            $("#circleholder div.circle2").addClass("activecircle")
        };

        function circle3 () {       
            $("#slider div.slide, #slideinfo p").fadeOut(1000)
            $("#slider div:eq(2), #slideinfo p:eq(2)").fadeIn(1000)
            $("*").removeClass("activecircle")
            $("#circleholder div.circle3").addClass("activecircle")
        };

        function circle4 () {       
            $("#slider div.slide, #slideinfo p").fadeOut(1000)
            $("#slider div:eq(3), #slideinfo p:eq(3)").fadeIn(1000)
            $("*").removeClass("activecircle")
            $("#circleholder div.circle4").addClass("activecircle")
        };

        function circle5 () {       
            $("#slider div.slide, #slideinfo p").fadeOut(1000)
            $("#slider div:eq(4), #slideinfo p:eq(4)").fadeIn(1000)
            $("*").removeClass("activecircle")
            $("#circleholder div.circle5").addClass("activecircle")
        };


});
```

Comment: The `clearInterval` function is most likely what you're looking for to do what you want.

Comment: Thought it probably would be, but I'm just not sure how to implement it in this instance.

Comment: Steps should be something like: `click` event happens -> clear original interval -> set new interval

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doKpzx

I just wrote mini slideshow, it is expandable you dont need to manually write events.

```
var btns = $('.btns'),
    cont = $('.slideshow'),
    slides = cont.find('.slide'),
    index = slides.filter('.show').index() || 0,
    delay = 1,
    duration = 1,
    timer;

slides.eq(index).addClass('show');
createDots();
selectDot();
addEvents();

function createDots(){
  var n = slides.length, dots = btns.children('.dots');
  while (n--) dots.append($('<div class="dot">'));  
}

function selectDot(){
  btns.find('.dots .dot').removeClass('active')
    .eq(index).addClass('active');
}

function addEvents() {
  btns.find('.prev').click(function(){
    index = --index; 
    if (index<0) index=slides.length-1;
    updateSlides();
  });
  btns.find('.next').click(function(){
    index = ++index % slides.length; 
    updateSlides();
  });
  btns.find('.dot').click(function(){
    index =  $(this).index();
    updateSlides();
  });
}

function updateSlides() {
  selectDot(); 
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    slides.not('.show').hide();
   slides.filter('.show').removeClass('show')
    .stop().fadeOut(duration*1000);
    slides.eq(index).fadeIn(duration*1000).addClass('show');
  },delay*1000);
}
```